# TSQL: If statement inside a With statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My problem is that I want to merge two SPs in one. the skeleton of the resulting sp is:

```
 with Paging(RowNo, ID, Name, Description, LengthSeconds, Rating, Url, ThumbnailFileName, AddedAt) AS
    (
     (if(@SortType is null)
      begin
         ... select ... 
      end
      else 
      begin
        ... select...
      end
    )

   select * from Paging ...
```

Can I do that If in the with statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No,,, it would be something like

```
with Paging(RowNo, ID, Name, Description, LengthSeconds, Rating, Url, ThumbnailFileName, AddedAt) AS
(
     select ... 

     WHERE @SortType is not null
     UNION ALL
     select ... 

     WHERE @SortType is null
)...
```

If the query is that simple though, then you wouldn't need a CTE: it doesn't add any readibility

Comment: how can I do paging without CTE?

Comment: You can do paging by adding the OVER clause "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY..." to the CTE, then a BETWEEN to page against the row numbers.

Comment: Paging will be even easier in SQL Server 2011 with `FETCH` and `OFFSET`. Stil no support for referencing next/previous row in the `OVER` clause though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `union` where the top side corresponds to the first half of the `if`:

```
select  ...
where   @SortType is null
union all
select  ...
where   @SortType not null null
```

An `if` statement is not allowed inside a query, only to control flow around queries.  So an `if` inside a `with` is not allowed.